# How can I write a text to speech c++ program for a beaglebone?

Tags: c++, audio, text-to-speech, beagleboneblack

I'm working on a Beaglebone and I want to write a program in c++ that speaks some text.

I can do it from the terminal with:

```
pico2wave -w test.wav "Testing 1 2 3"
mplayer –ao alsa:device=hw=5 test.wav
```

How can I write a text to speech program with c++?

Comment: The simplest solution? By calling those programs from the C++ program (search for and read about the `system` function).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I did that and it almost worked. For some reason I get the error: "mplayer: could not connect to socket", even though the command works fine when running directly on the terminal.